# Cascading Multi select pick lists CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, multi-select, picklist

I Have multi select pick list which work fine however it now contains around 70 options to select from with around 12 categories - I have searched around the internet to find a solution that could make the list a little more user friendly.

It would be perfect if I was able to have the pick list with the 12 categories and on select of them they cascade in to their sub options. However the tricky part is this has to be done from within the same field.

Has anyone had a similar request or know of anyway to make this possible?

Thank You

here is the code for the multi select pick list I have currently:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title>
<script src="sc_json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor; font-family: Segoe UI; font-size: 11px; background-color: rgb(246, 248, 250);" onload="onload()">
<div id="MultiSelectField"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var FORM_TYPE_CREATE = 1;
        var FORM_TYPE_UPDATE = 2;
        var FORM_TYPE_READ_ONLY = 3;
        var FORM_TYPE_DISABLED = 4;
        var FORM_TYPE_QUICK_CREATE = 5;
        var FORM_TYPE_BULK_EDIT = 6;

        var var_sc_optionset;
        var var_sc_optionsetvalue;
        var options;
        var checkedValues;
        var isDirty = false;
        var html = "";

        function onload() {
            var formType = parent.Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
            if (formType == FORM_TYPE_BULK_EDIT) {
                displayMessage();
            }
            else {
                init();
            }
        }

        function init() {
            getParameters();
            getOptionSetValues();
            getCheckedValues();
            convertToMultiSelect();

        }

        function displayMessage() {
            MultiSelectField.innerHTML = "This field cannot be displayed or edited in this form mode.";
        }

        function getParameters() {
            var querystring = unescape(window.location.search.replace('?', '').replace('data=', ''));
            var params = querystring.split(',');

            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    var_sc_optionset = params[i];
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    var_sc_optionsetvalue = params[i];
                }
            }
        }

        //populate option-set values and integers
        function getOptionSetValues() {
            options = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(var_sc_optionset).getOptions();
        }

        function getCheckedValues() {
            var dirtyCheckedOptions = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(var_sc_optionsetvalue).getValue();
            if (dirtyCheckedOptions != null) {
                checkedValues = dirtyCheckedOptions.split(';');
            }
            else {
                checkedValues = '';
            }

        }

        //Method to convert an optionset to multi select Option Set
        function convertToMultiSelect() {


            for (var i = 0; i < options.length - 1; i++) {
                var pOption = options[i];
                if (!isChecked(pOption.text))
                    html += "<input type='checkbox' class='multiselect_cb' onclick='makeDirty()' style='border:none; width:25px; align:left;' title='" + pOption.text + "'/>";
                else
                    html += "<input type='checkbox' class='multiselect_cb' checked='checked' onclick='makeDirty()' style='border:none; width:25px; align:left;' title='" + pOption.text + "'/>";

                html += "<label>" + pOption.text + "</label>";
                if (i != options.length - 2) {
                    html += "<br/>"; //it's a 'br' flag 
                }
            }
            MultiSelectField.innerHTML = html;

        }

        function makeDirty() {
            isDirty = true;
        }

        function isChecked(ptext) {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkedValues.length; i++) {
                if (checkedValues[i] == ptext)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        function saveMultiSelect() {
            if (isDirty) {
                var divElement = document.getElementById("MultiSelectField");
                var result = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < divElement.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    if (divElement.childNodes[i].type == "checkbox" && divElement.childNodes[i].checked) {
                        result += divElement.childNodes[i].title + ";";
                    }
                }
                //clear out the previous results from the field
                parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(var_sc_optionsetvalue).setValue("");
                //populate var_sc_optionsetvalue with the checked values
                parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(var_sc_optionsetvalue).setValue(result);
                isDirty = false;
            }
        }

    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: So you have 82 `OptionSetValues` in your `OptionSet`?  70 are 70 are basically sub options, and 12 are the main categories?

Comment: Hi Daryl, Really sorry for no reply! but yeah that's the jist of it mines down to about 3 sub levels.

Comment: The optionsetvalues are displayed as multiselect check boxes using the multiselect solution